# How to appear an image after the user entered the correct answer?

Tags: javascript

So im writing a web page as a small birthday gift for my friend, but I have never learned javascript...
What I want is that after he entered the correct answer, an image will appear as a reward.

```
while(1)
{
    var pro1=prompt("question");

    if (pro1=="answer")
      ***appear an image;*** //this is the part of the code I don't know how to write

    alert("you answer is wrong");
```

Sorry...I know this is kind of basic, if you are willing to help me, that would be a big favor.

Comment: Add your HTML and CSS codes so we also know what to show, and how you made it.

Comment: create a function called `appearAnImage` ... then call `appearAnImage()` ... done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, changing the src to whatever image you actually want linked:

```js
while(1) {
  var pro1=prompt("question");
  if (pro1=="answer"){
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('img')).src = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8c88f69ca0d0f966d994fa481a364060?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1';
    break;
  }
  alert("you answer is wrong");
}
```

But using `prompt` is very user-unfriendly, you might want to try to finding a better way.

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches.
If you are checking the answer through ajax then in the ajax response you can display an image ie, in the initial page load success image will there in the page but it will be hidden using display:none css. So in the ajax respose based on the answer you can show the image by removing display:none. Either you can put the image in the span and assign an id for the span or you can assign id to the img tag, using this id you can show or hide the element.

```
var pro1=prompt("question");

if (pro1=="answer"){
    $("#ImgId").show();
}
else{
    alert("you answer is wrong");
    $("#ImgId").hide();
}
```